# Use a HTML code in any one of multiple partial views in Asp.net MVC 4 with Razor View Engine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using Asp.net MVC4 with Razor View Engine. I have a View Page (It's a full view page means not a layout page or any child page), in this page I am using three partial views. And I have a piece of HTML code which must be appear on the page only once, but the condition is that it can be on any one of the partial views.

Suppose I have a view e.g. view1.cshtml 
and three partial views  partialview1.cshtml, partialview2.cshtml, partialview3.cshtml 
My required piece of HTML code can be on any one of the partial page but may be it is on partialview1 or partialview2 or partialview3

So how can I check if the code is defined on any other partial view so that I can define that on other partial view.

I know it sounds so complicated and confusing but please help me.... Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried the `ViewBag`?

Comment: Can you give some more details, something more concrete about your particular problem? The reason I am asking you this is because sharing data in such way between separate partial views is not a good approach. You are building dependencies where there should be none. So maybe there is a way to refactor your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another partial (partialview4.cshtml), use it on all the partials partialview(1-3).cshtml.
Pass on the model of the partial if its supposed to display or not :-)
The view1.cshtml will know how to control.

```
@Html.RenderPartial("partialview1", new yourPartialViewModel {displayHtmlSample = true});
@Html.RenderPartial("partialview2", new yourPartialViewModel {displayHtmlSample = false});
@Html.RenderPartial("partialview3", new yourPartialViewModel {displayHtmlSample = false});
```

Inside the partial:

```
    @if(Model.displayHtmlSample) { 
      @Html.RenderPartial("partialview4")
    }
```

Comment: Ohh Thanks.......... I wonder how can It did not come in my mind, may be due to stress, I think I should take some rest... by the way thank you so much...